Making Australia more humid
I need Australia to support vast areas of african savanna-like environment, and if possible mammoth steppe-like in the colder regions. Turning the deserts into savanna would be a requisite.
What would be the best way to make Australia more humid, and if possible a little bit colder? would moving the Great Dividing Range to the west help?

What is the scope of your effort? Are you wanting to adjust the way the earth simply exists in your setting, or is this it about a human effort to terraform the continent?

Yeah, I'm trying to adjust earth in the setting.

The southernmost point of mainland Australia is at 44° southern latitude. (For comparison, Boston, Cannes and Marseilles are at 42–44° northern latitude.) You cannot make it colder without moving it at least a thousand miles to the south.

Cant find it now but recalling something I read many years ago, closing the "Drake Passage" might be your ticket. Screws up a bunch of other places though.

you can make it wetter by moving it north and east, to make it cooler instead you would have to move it nearly 30 degrees south. either way reducing the height of the great divide will help a lot.

Divert the southern jet stream
That particular air current currently skims the bottom of Australia. The jet stream would have to be moved to the north east by a large new landmass.
By placing a new subcontinent directly to the south west of Australia, you should be able to affect it enough to move it. Once the jet sweeps through Australia, you could have a climate that is similar to the UK. Well, at least in the regions closest to the western coast.
Mind you, there is really no telling what the new landmass will do. It could have the opposite effect and push the stream further south. Either option would likely have a large effect on the southern ecosystems.


You wouldn't even need a lot of land as long as it was steep, a good, but narrow mountain range would do.

In addition to JustAnotherUser's perfectly good suggestion:
You could reverse the Indian Ocean's southern gyre, this would bring a lot of humid air that currently ends up in the Southern Ocean to the west coast of Australia. This would however require reversing the spin of the Earth, since gyre rotation is created by Coriolis. That's going to change the whole world, all the ocean gyres, and atmospheric movements will be reversed, that's going to switch the pacific upwelling pattern similar to what happens during El Nino only more so, that makes the east coast of Australia drier and the west coast of South America much harder to make a living on. The majority of the interior of Australia is going to remain dry unless you shift the latitude of the whole continent, because as it stands it sits in the tropical desert zone meaning that there is a steady fall of bone dry air from Hadley Cell circulation.
Not sure what will happen to the thermohaline conveyor, since basin form has a lot of bearing on that, if the shape or direction of the conveyor changes then everything is up for grabs in terms of changes to global climate and could undo the local changes outlined above.
Speaking from a purely kiwi perspective any effort to make Australia more hospitable is a total waste anyway, not worth the hassle.
